# IsMemberOf() returns false incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, directoryservices

I'm am creating an ASP.net intranet site and I'm trying to get group membership.  I have the following code:

```cs
PrincipalContext cntxt = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
GroupPrincipal adminGroup = new GroupPrincipal(cntxt, "Help");
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(cntxt, "domainuser");

var boolvalue =user.IsMemberOf(adminGroup);
```

boolvalue is returning as false.

If I debug with:

```cs
var foo = User.GetGroups();
```

I get a list of all the groups that the user is a member of.

but

```cs
var bar = adminGroup.GetMembers();
```

shows that it can't seem to get the group from AD as all the members are null.

I've tried using

```cs
PrincipalContext cntxt =new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ADdomain.local");
```

but that didn't fix the issue.

I'm not getting any build or syntax errors either.